# i am unable to see IDENTITY components in login page in communities?

Tags: customer-community, community-builder, partner-communities, lightning-community

I am able to see Identity components in my personal Org ,But not able to see in company org. Is there any check box available to enable the Identity components in my company org.

Comment: We had the same scenario and had to log a case to Salesforce support to get this working.

Answer (score 3):

I had experienced the same scenario during one of our implementations and then had to contact Salesforce support. Identity components were available once Salesforce support most likely enabled a setting from the backend.

**Note**: This had to be done for all orgs that we had. So you may like to open a case with all org ids to be able to have identity components available in all the orgs with one case instead of following up separately on each one of those.

Comment: sure i will raise the ticket in sales force thanks!

Comment: @mike also if you can update it back here, once you hear back from the support so that anyone in same situation gets help to make sure they know this as a resolution.

Comment: yes, i raised the ticket with the salesforce and now i am able to view the identity components in the community portal.